# Switch statement to return result only when item type changes

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, switch-statement, reactjs

I have an array of content that when simplified looks like this:

```
[
 { content_type: 1, content_body: "some text" },

 { content_type: 1, content_body: "some text" },

 { content_type: 2, content_body: "media link" },

 { content_type: 1, content_body: "some text" }
]
```

I now need to map through this array and have a switch statement checking `content_type` and rendering HTML based on it, so something like (note below syntax uses jsx, so it might look different from vanila JavaScript, but it is pretty self explanatory).

```
switch(item.content_type) {
 case 1:
   render (
     <div class="text_content">
       <p>{item.content_body}</p>
     </div>

   )
  case 2:
   render (
     <div class="text_media">
       <div>{item.content_body}</div>
     </div>

   )
}
```

Now the issue, If same content type follows one after another in the array (so first 2 entries with content_type 1 for example), I want their content_bodies to be rendered inside one div, so

```
<div class="text_content">
  <p>{item.content_body}</p>
  <p>{item.content_body}</p>
</div>
```

and then continue on if next content_type is different. (This can be repeated several times in the app, also this is only repeated for content_type 1).

What would be an approach for this? Bear in mind I can't manipulate array to do things like nest those contents inside an object.

Comment: You just need to remember the last `content_type`. If this item is the same as last, don't wrap the body in the div.

Comment: @quamrana, but in that case won't it just render it after the div.text_content, as opposed to inside of it?

Comment: Sorry, that's right. You'll need to close the last div and open a new one on change of `content_type`. And close the very last div after the end of the list.

Comment: @Ilja will `div` elements with different class types be on the page already?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your approach correctly then this should work just fine.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrMEjz - working example

Code included below. Logic is that on each iteration it will check if an element exists then new element is inserted inside, if not, create that element and add element inside. (Note: jQuery included as a library, you can get away with using base JS but I wanted to show you the idea with slightly less code)

```js
// sample array 
var arr = [
  {content_type: 1, content_body: "some text"},
  {content_type: 1, content_body: "some text"},
  {content_type: 2, content_body: "media link"},
  {content_type: 1, content_body: "some text"}
  ];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var currentElement = arr[i]; console.log(currentElement.content_body);
  
  switch(currentElement.content_type) {
    case 1:
      var el = jQuery('.text_content');
      
      if(el.length) {
        el.append('<p>' + currentElement.content_body + '</p>');
      } else {
        var el = jQuery('<div class="text_content"></div>')
        el.append('<p>' + currentElement.content_body + '</p>');
        jQuery('body').append(el);
      }
      break;
    case 2:
      var el = jQuery('.text_media');
      
      if(el.length) {
        el.append('<div>' + currentElement.content_body + '</div>');
      } else {
        var el = jQuery('<div class="text_media"></div>');
        el.append('<p>' + currentElement.content_body + '</p>');
        jQuery('body').append(el);
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
.text_content {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.text_content p {
  border: 1px solid yellowgreen;
}

.text_media {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps, let me know if it requires tweaking. Cheers.

Comment: @JacobHeater right, I haven't touched React but I'm pretty sure given the logic this can be achieved the same way given the `render()` function will do the same as jQuery wrapping. Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: He is using React.js with JSX. This is a jQuery based approach, I don't think it will solve his problem.

Comment: Actually, nothing about the two approaches are the same. One is jQuery, the other is React. One is JSX, the other is strings. You're oversimplifying it greatly.